# How to capture the play video action in YouTube player for Android

Tags: android, youtube-api

I have YouTube player embedded in an Android application. I play videos using the following class:

```
public class YoutubePlayerActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener {

    private static final String TAG =  YoutubePlayerActivity.class.getSimpleName();

    private YouTubePlayerView playerView;
    private Toolbar toolbar;
    private int minuto;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        Log.d(TAG , "onCreate(Bundle) - Ini ");

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_player);
        toolbar= (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
      //  setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle(R.string.app_name);
        toolbar.setTitleTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.com_facebook_button_background_color_focused));

        playerView = (YouTubePlayerView) findViewById(R.id.player_view);
        playerView.initialize(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY, this);


        Log.d(TAG , "onCreate(Bundle) - Fi ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean b) {

        Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationSuccess(Provider, YouTubePlayer, boolean ) - Ini ");

        if(!b) {
            youTubePlayer.play();
            youTubePlayer.cueVideo(getIntent().getStringExtra("VIDEO_ID"));
            minuto =  youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();



        }

        Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationSuccess(Provider, YouTubePlayer, boolean ) - Fi ");

    }

    @Override
    public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

        Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationFailure(Provider, YouTubeInitializationResult) - Ini ");

        Toast.makeText(this, getString(R.string.player_failed), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG , "onInitializationFailure(Provider, YouTubeInitializationResult) - Fi ");
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed () {

    }
}
```

I want to capture the event of clicking play video. Is there a way to capture the event of playing the video?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

to capture the button like playing, pausing you can set the youtube playback like this

```
playerView.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
```

where playback listener is declared like this:

```
private PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new PlaybackEventListener()    {

    @Override
    public void onBuffering(boolean arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onPlaying() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onSeekTo(int arg0) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStopped() {
    }

};
```